# Syntax Error changing Registry Value

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have code that is supposed to change the registered owner of my copy of Windows, however I keep getting a syntax error. I looked at the REG ADD Syntax on the Microsoft website and still I cant figure it out. Yes, I am new to batch scripting.

```
    :Change
    set /p user=Set your new owner name: 
    REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion /v RegisteredOwner /t REG_SZ /d %user% /f
    pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the key name, change it to:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v RegisteredOwner /t REG_SZ /d %user% /f
```